# in org-mode, how to protect stars from deletion?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, aquamacs

I use org-mode in org-indent-mode, meaning all the stars but one are hidden, but the levels retain their indentation, creating an outline-type effect.

When I'm editing, I always seem to accidentally delete the space between the star and the text. Which means that this:

[image]

gets all messed up and turns into this:

[image]

Or sometimes, even worse, I even delete the space AND one or more of the stars. Then I have to figure out where I am and try to reenter the right number of stars to get me back to the right level, which is a pain.

This question might be against the spirit of org-mode, but is there a way to "protect" the stars and the space after them, such that when I hit <kbd>delete</kbd> multiple times, it sends me back up to the previous line of text rather than deleting the stars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the code:

```
(defun new-org-delete-backward-char (N)
  (interactive "p")
  (if (not (looking-back "[*]+ "))
      (org-delete-backward-char N)
    (previous-line)
    (end-of-line)))

(add-hook 
 'org-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
   (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "DEL") 
     'new-org-delete-backward-char)))
```

I was messing up my outlines too, before I've defined
`org-speed-commands-user` to do stuff like insert heading up, down etc.
Maybe you'd like to try that instead. Also, this is quite useful:

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-a")
              (lambda()(interactive)
                (if (looking-at "^[^*]")
                    (re-search-backward "^*")
                  (org-beginning-of-line))))
```

It brings you to the beginning of heading once you're already
at the beginning of line, when you press <kbd>C-a</kbd>.

### UPD

This version has provisioning for deleting region and goes to the end of the line:

```
(defun new-org-delete-backward-char (N)
  (interactive "p")
  (cond ((region-active-p)
         (delete-region
          (region-beginning)
          (region-end)))
        ((looking-back "[*]+ ")
         (previous-line)
         (end-of-line))
        (t
         (org-delete-backward-char N))))
```

Comment: @abo-abo The second snippet you posted is not working on my system. However, this one is: `(defun safe-org-beginning-of-line ()
  "Goto beginning of line or just in front of the headline"
  (interactive)
  (if (looking-at "^\*")
      (while (looking-at "[\* ]")
 (forward-char 1))
    (org-beginning-of-line)))`

Comment: The usual way to debug these things is just to press `f1 k` then the key.
And voila - you know how the key is named.

Comment: There's something slightly off with the spacing though. Sometimes when I delete through, it takes me not to the end of the line but one character left of that (i.e. I'm hovering on the second character in "foo" instead of the third one). Other times it works though. Is this fixable? ... My other question is, now when I highlight a region and hit <kbd>delete</kbd>, it doesn't delete the region. Can this be reimplemented? Thanks!

Comment: @elemakil, I don't think that you got the point.
My function goes back to current heading, no matter how far away it is.
Your function skips stars, once it's at the beginning of line.  Still useful,
but entirely different.

Comment: @abo-abo Indeed! I always used it from inside a heading because I misunderstood what you want to achieve. Sorry for that.